# NameError: name 'Ridge' is not defined

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, anaconda, spyder

I'm beginner learning Machine learning. I'm using IDLE spyder
and this Python version:

```
Python 3.4.3 |Anaconda 2.3.0 (64-bit)| (default, Mar  6 2015, 12:06:10) [MSC v.1600 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

I'm having the following error:

```
NameError: name 'Ridge' is not defined
```

Can you please help me to find out what's wrong with this code? Is this issue related with the Python version?

```
from sklearn import linear_model
clf = linear_model.Ridge(alpha=.5)
clf.fit ([[0, 0], [0, 0], [1, 1]], [0, .1, 1]) 
Ridge(alpha=0.5, copy_X=True, fit_intercept=True, max_iter=None,
      normalize=False, random_state=None, solver='auto', tol=0.001)
clf.coef_
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you see the difference between the two ways you invoke Ridge?

Comment: Did you install it ? pip install scikit-learn ?

Comment: I'm using spyder IDLE and running Anaconda throught it. scikit-learn is pre-installed. This is the version

Comment: Python 3.4.3 |Anaconda 2.3.0 (64-bit)| (default, Mar  6 2015, 12:06:10) [MSC v.1600 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

Comment: The error message told you the error: `Ridge` is not defined.  It is an attribute of `linear_model`, but it is not defined in the global scope.  Just as you did with `clf`, you need to use `linear_model.Ridge`

Answer (score 3):

Please see the difference between the two code snippets below, the first of which is correct and the second produces an error:

**First**:

```
from sklearn import linear_model
clf = linear_model.Ridge (alpha = .5)
clf.fit([[0, 0], [0, 0], [1, 1]], [0, .1, 1])
clf.coef_
array([ 0.34545455,  0.34545455])
```

**Second:**

```
from sklearn import linear_model
clf = linear_model.Ridge (alpha = .5)
clf.fit ([[0, 0], [0, 0], [1, 1]], [0, .1, 1]) 
Ridge(alpha=0.5, copy_X=True, fit_intercept=True, max_iter=None,
  normalize=False, random_state=None, solver='auto', tol=0.001)
clf.coef_
NameError: name 'Ridge' is not defined
```

**Edit**:

you should run the lines from the first code snippets line by line in Python interpreter (or in a cell as a whole in Ipython notebook) and you'll get the line

```
Ridge(alpha=0.5, copy_X=True, fit_intercept=True, max_iter=None,
   normalize=False, random_state=None, solver='auto', tol=0.001)
```

in the ***output*** after you have executed `clf.fit([[0, 0], [0, 0], [1, 1]], [0, .1, 1])` statement.

Comment: thanks.  I ran this .Though I'm not getting error now,but I'm not noticing any output which you mentioned                                                                       from sklearn import linear_model
clf = linear_model.Ridge (alpha = .5)
clf.fit([[0, 0], [0, 0], [1, 1]], [0, .1, 1])

Comment: @Jossi, try copying and running lines from 1st snippet line by line and watch out the output...